"Vivre d'une vie" - Quelle est la nuance sémantique ?

[Le personnage romanesque] ne vit-il pas d'une vie propre, qui s'impose au lecteur ?

Venant de lire la tournure ci-dessus, je me demande quelle est la différence sémantique entre celle-ci et « vivre une vie propre ». Dans le second cas il s'agit d'un complément d'objet interne. Mais dans le premier avons-nous affaire à l'article partitif ou à la préposition de ?
Merci beaucoup de vos réponses !

Pas facile à expliquer. Mais la différence, s'il y en a vraiment une, est très, très mince. On peut dire les deux. C'est peut-être simplement une différence de style, pas de sens.

C'est un peu difficile à dire sans connaitre l'auteur, le contexte, le raisonnement qui préside à ce bout de phrase...

Une vie propre = une vie [qui lui est] propre = une vie personnelle et unique, voulue par l'auteur, mais différente dans la tête de chaque lecteur.

C'est difficile de se prononcer sur un morceau de phrase sans connaître la logique développée dans le paragraphe, l'auteur... "vivre d'une vie" pourrait être une formulation banale chez un romantique du XIXè siècle mais relever d'une recherche de connotation plus intentionnelle chez un contemporain.
L'hypothèse de l'article partitif me paraît exclue puisque la vie en question ne nous intéresse pas en tant que tout indénombrable (c'est une vie, celle qui s'impose au lecteur), contrairement par exemple à

Je vais t'en donner, de la vie propre, moi !

En revanche,

Il vit d'une vie propre

répond à la question "comment vit-il ?" C'est un complément de manière introduit par une simple préposition.

Il vit une vie propre

répondrait quant à lui à la question "que vit-il ?".
Les deux angles d'approche sont très similaires. Le premier est d'un registre plus soutenu. Le deuxième étant plus simple et le COD ayant une force plus directe qu'un complément circonstanciel, la vie elle-même est plus immédiatement et clairement ce dont on parle, au lieu du personnage et la manière dont il vit.
Dans le même ordre d'idée, on pourrait avancer que l'auteur concède le fait que cette existence est tout de même d'un genre spécial, imaginaire, puisqu'il juge nécessaire d'en qualifier la manière de vivre.

Le personnage romanesque ne vit-il pas [comme s'il était animé] d'une vie propre ?

Mais encore une fois difficile à dire sans contexte.

Merci, Guillaume, de votre réponse utile !
Le contexte est celui d'un commentaire d'œuvre littéraire où il est question du personnage principal. J'avais vu mal la possibilité de s'interroger sur le "comment", qui entraînerait le C de manière, mais ce qui l'explique toutefois bien. Il se peut que ces tournures plus soutenues prennent plus de temps à distinguer pour le débutant.

Troisième fois que je tape une réponse car en effet c'est délicat...
Seul l'auteur peut répondre à ce genre de question; j'ai tendance à penser qu'à défaut toutes les réponses sont possibles (dans la limite de la correction de la langue).
J'ai vu initialement ce

Vivre d'une vie propre

Uniquement comme un groupe prépositionnel/complément circonstanciel de moyen (de quoi vit-il? Qu'est-ce qui lui suffit pour vivre? Sa vie elle-même, si riche et foisonnante, aux possibilités infinies qu'offre l'imaginaire des romans, et qui va s'imposer au lecteur).
Mais en me creusant la tête j'ai fait un parallèle avec "se vêtir d'une chemise", où le d' serait bien un simple article partitif. Donc si on suit cette logique, on pourrait vivre d'une vie comme on s'habille d'une chemise (ou d'un habit, pour garder la proximité lexicale).
Se nourrir de nourriture, boire trop de boisson, chanter du chant grégorien, etc. Dans le cas présent, un procédé suivi pour éviter le simple COD!

Dans se vêtir d'une chemise, chemise est complément de moyen. Dans boire trop de boisson, boisson est complément de l'adverbe.

La question posée est celle de l'autonomie du personnage de fiction d'une part, de sa vraisemblance d'autre part, autrement dit de sa crédibilité auprès du lecteur. Celui-ci, dès le début du texte romanesque, doit pouvoir accepter le projet, page après page, tel que l'auteur l'a organisé: la pertinence des premières pages est capitale.
L'accroche, la mise en place de l'environnement, les lieux et leur incidence sur le récit, le temps, tout doit concourir à créer un univers particulier, avec sa cohérence et ses logiques. Le(s) personnage(s), pour s'imposer au lecteur, doit présenter des caractéristiques repérables dans un récit suscitant lui même une adhésion persistante pour intéresser quelques lecteurs d'abord, s'assurer d'une curiosité continue, et donc l'expression d'une satisfaction mentale suffisante pour que se mette en place un effet d'adhésion de groupe.
La persistance d'un personnage de roman HORS de son récit, son infiltration dans le tissu culturel comme un modèle (positif ou négatif) est une possibilité, qui doit sa réalisation à tant de facteurs aléatoires, qu'on ne peut que constater son existence, après coup, et après consensus et durabilité : sa vie propre.
Un personnage, donc, le temps de la lecture, s'impose de fait au lecteur : s'il ne réussit pas à s'installer dans son esprit, le livre rejoindra son étagère. Mais c'est l'ensemble récit-personnages qui doit fonctionner
pour assurer un minimum de visibilité et de mémorisation à un personnage en particulier.
Il existe une autre "vie propre" du personnage, encore plus difficile à étudier que l'émergence et la durée d'un personnage romanesque. Il est une constatation partagée par beaucoup de romanciers : il arrive parfois que le personnage échappe à l'auteur. Avec surprise, et quelque inquiétude, il voit son personnage s'imposer à lui de telle manière que le plan de son livre, tel que prévu, est significativement modifié. Il appartient au talent de l'auteur de gérer au mieux ces velléités d'indépendance.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
